What verb and subjective fits for synaptic current?
From Wikipedia's entry for Synapse:

In the nervous system, a synapse is a structure that permits a neuron (or nerve cell) to pass an electrical or chemical signal to another neuron or to the target effector cell. Synapses are essential to the transmission of nervous impulses from one neuron to another,

My question is what is the best verb and subjective for describing end-to-end (one point to another) transfer of current in neurons and synapses? Some verbs I've thought of:

to send
to transfer
to transmit
to transport
to propagate
to pass

And some adjectives:

a transfer
a transmission
a transport
a propagation
a passage

If it matters I want to keep my writing informal but accurate and precise.

Note that 'propagate' doesn't mean to a specific target, but spread generally.

All your "adjectives" are nouns.

I think a common word in neurology is "signal". Neurons transmit signals.

I generally recommend that if you're looking for a technical term, you're better off asking in the SE site devoted to the field, rather than ELU. Our experts know the lay language well, but are not generally well versed in industry jargon. So [biology.se] may be a better place to ask this.

As Barmar says, a dedicated site is more appropriate here.
